# how can i create an equivalent "$" effect on mouseclick events in AHK?

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to create an AHK script where the right mouse click is intercepted, similar to a $ call would work with a keyboard press. This is the code I've tried but the right click still is sent to the program.

```
$capslock::
send {u down}
var = 0
return

$capslock up::
send {u up}
var = 1
return

$rbutton::
if(var) {
;
} else
sendinput, {s}
return
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. If you want to block the right mouse button, use: 'RButton::MsgBox RButton click blocked' and if not '~RButton::MsgBox RButton Not blocked'. [The $ prefix has no effect for mouse hotkeys, since they always use the mouse hook](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: I'm trying to swap hotkeys for a game when capslock is pressed and a mode is switched on (target champions only, for league of legends, if you're curious). I need an alternative to $ as the right click is being sent anyway regardless of that solution.

Comment: I think the problem is related to LOL then because it works in all other apps I tested, sorry.

Comment: I think you might not be understanding what `$` does. It prevents a hotkey from firing itself if called within its own hotkey. Anyway, since you're essentially using `capslock` as a modifier key, have you tried something like `capslock & rbutton::msgbox`?